# Contractibility of connected holomorphic dynamics?

Tags: gn.general-topology, ds.dynamical-systems, cv.complex-variables, fractals

Let $f$ be a function, holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}$,  and $K(f)$ its non-escaping set : 
$$K(f) = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : f^{(k)}(z)  \nrightarrow_{k \to \infty} \infty \} $$

> **Question** : If $K(f)$ is connected, is it also contractible ?

Comment: It is not even known if $K(f)$ must be path connected.

Comment: @AdamEpstein : thank you, for your comment. So it's an hard open problem... Do you know if "$K(f)$ path-connected $\Rightarrow$ contractible" is also open ?

Comment: Offhand I don't know. But any locally connected example will be a dendrite, hence contractible.

Comment: What do you really mean by "holomorphic function"? A polynomial? Or your question applies to transcendental entire functons (for which $K(f)$ is NOT called the filled in Julia set).

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko : My question applies to all the holomorphic functions. What's the name of $K(f)$ in the general case ? Also, is it known to be true in the polynomial case ?

Comment: @AdamEpstein : do you know a "numerical" counter-example ("numerical" means a picture, on which we can "see" that the set is connected but not contractible) ?

Comment: Holomorphic WHERE? Entire? Adam already explained to you that  this is unknown in the polynomial case. But in the entire case is is probably wrong. What is the exact definition of "contractible" for a set which is neither open nor closed ?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko : holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$. Do you know a numerical counter-example?

Comment: Functions holomorpic in C are called entire. I am sure Adam can tell you a true (not numerical) counterexample. Just tell him that you are asking about entire transcendental functions.

Comment: @AdamEpstein : (after Alexandre's comment) I'm asking about all the functions holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}$, not only the polynomial ones. Do you know a counter-example of entire transcendental function, as Alexandre said ?

Comment: I believe that the answer is negative, probably for every quadratic Cremer polynomial. It shouldn't be too hard to prove, but I probably won't have a chance to think about it carefully enough for a couple of days. If no-one has written an answer by then, I will try.

Comment: For entire functions, the question is even more weird, because the set is no longer closed (nor open). Distinctions such as whether the set itself is connected, or only connected when you add infinity, will also become important.

Comment: @LasseRempe-Gillen : thank you for your comment. Meantime a proof, do you have a picture showing it's not true for these polynomials ? Next, I'm not sure to understand, isn't contractibility well defined for the entire functions ?

Comment: @Sébastien Palcoux:  I wonder if it is reasonable to expect to produce an informative picture. The reason I am skeptical is that a sequence of Siegel quadratic polynomials  can converge to a Cremer quadratic polynomial, and  in such a situation the filled-Julia sets will converge in the Hausdorff sense - so by definition, the Cremer  picture will be visually indistinguishable from the Siegel pictures, many of which will be locally connected and contractible.

As for the transcendental case, Alexandre and Lasse raise an important issue concerning closedness and connectedness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question is negative.

**EDIT** I have added some additional details and made some corrections.

**In the entire case**, it is possible to construct an entire function with the following properties: 
(a) The Fatou set consists of a single conneted attracting basin;
(b) If $C$ is a component of the Julia set, then the set of non-escaping points in $C$ is totally disconnected (in fact has Hausdorff dimension zero),
(c) There is a component of $J(f)$ that contains a non-escaping point, but no point that is accessible from $F(f)$.

Now, by (a), the nonescaping set is connected (since it contains a dense connected subset of the plane). On the other hand, it can be shown that there is no curve connecting the non-escaping points in (c) to a point in the Fatou set without intersecting the escaping set.

Hence the non-escaping set is not path-wise connected, and hence not contractible. (The construction is contained in an upcoming article of mine, dealing more generally with the topology of transcendental Julia sets.)

For **quadratic Cremer polynomials**, the key point is that the Cremer point $z_0$ is accumulated on by small cycles by work of Yoccoz. Now, if the Julia set is path-connected (otherwise, there is nothing to prove), then there is a unique arc connecting each of these periodic points to $z_0$.

Now, for any cycle, it follows from the work of Perez-Marco that at least one of the corresponding arcs has diameter at least $\delta$, for $\delta$ independent of the cycle. Indeed, I believe it follows that at least one of them must contain the critical point.

From this, one can deduce (although I haven't made sure to check all the details) that the Julia set is not contractible.

Comment: Thank you for this outline ! I'm not sure to well understand about the quadratic Cremer polynomials: do they disprove the weaker property "$0$-connected $\Rightarrow$ $1$-connected"? (If no, is this property still open in the entire case?)

Comment: In the entire transcendental case, are you sure that the non-escaping set is connected? (I did not understand your "hence", because the non-escaping set contains much more than the Fatou component).

Comment: @Alex - I will clarify. Sebastien - I don't understand. I believe contractibility is a stronger property than being 1-connected. In any case, I am not sure that it is known whether Cremer Julia sets can be pathwise connected.

Comment: @LasseRempe-Gillen : I thought you prove that it's not $1$-connected (because $1$-connected is weaker than contractible). But, in fact, you prove directly that it's not contractible. Thank you ! If $0$-connected Cremer filled Julia sets exist, do you know if they could be not $1$-connected ?

Comment: @Sebastien A Cremer Julia set has no interior and can never disconnect the plane, so - if I have my definitions right - every such Julia set is 1-connected.

Comment: My definition of [$1$-connected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-connected) is : with a trivial fundamental group **and** $0$-connected (i.e. path-connected). Because you don't know whether Cremer Julia sets can be $0$-connected, I guess you don't have the same definition. Anyway, you say that these sets have a trivial fundamental group.

Comment: Yes, they always have trivial fundamental group. This is trivial using standard results. After giving some thought to the matter, I believe, however, that Cremer quadratic Julia sets are quite unlikely to be path-connected.

Comment: @LasseRempe-Gillen : ok, thank you!  Is it true that the non-escaping set of every holomorphic function, has trivial fundamental group (by using your trivial standard results) ?

Comment: If by "holomorphic function" you mean "entire function", then the answer is yes (but this is really a different question). It may not be quite as trivial for transcendental maps as for polynomials, but is still true.